# Error Cannot match any routes. ionic iOS embed video not showing

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, embed

I am trying to display a embedded video on my iOS app. The android app and the browser (chrome and safari and mobile) work fine. Only the iOS app doesn’t work.

It is not the security or permissions. I went to great lengths to check those out. Well at least I don’t think it is those.

I’m getting an error that says "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ‘embed/iframe/…’ the error goes on from there. I’ll post it below lol. First I’ll show you my code…

HTML:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen *ngIf="sermon?.id === '1'" src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/nj4y9f0b7f?playerColor=3EC9A0&autoPlay=true&fullscreenButton=true&playButton=false&playsinline=false&preload=metadata&videoFoam=true&wmode=true&smallPlayButton=true"></iframe>

<iframe allowfullscreen *ngIf="sermon?.id === '2'" src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/xy2azhgzti?playerColor=3EC9A0&autoPlay=true&fullscreenButton=true&playButton=false&playsinline=false&preload=metadata&videoFoam=true&wmode=true&smallPlayButton=true"></iframe>

<iframe allowfullscreen *ngIf="sermon?.id === '3'" src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/svwxe6z9a1?playerColor=3EC9A0&autoPlay=true&fullscreenButton=true&playButton=false&playsinline=false&preload=metadata&videoFoam=true&wmode=true&smallPlayButton=true"></iframe>

<iframe allowfullscreen *ngIf="sermon?.id === '4'" src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/pbytxhvcpa?playerColor=3EC9A0&autoPlay=true&fullscreenButton=true&playButton=false&playsinline=false&preload=metadata&videoFoam=true&wmode=true&smallPlayButton=true"></iframe>
```

.ts file:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.dataProvider.load().subscribe((data: any) => {
      const sermonId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('sermonId');
      if (data && data.sermons) {
        for (const sermon of data.sermons) {
          if (sermon && sermon.id === sermonId) {
            this.sermon = sermon;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'embed/iframe/nj4y9f0b7f' noMatchError@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:457759 ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:457498 error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:431408 _error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66184 error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:65982 _error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66184 error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:65982 _error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66184 error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:65982 _error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66184 error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:65982 _error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66184 error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:65982 notifyError@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:510456 _error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:61140 error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:65982 _error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66184 error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:65982 _error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66184 error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:65982 error@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:431456 _complete@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:430529 complete@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66047 _complete@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66244 complete@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66047 _complete@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66244 complete@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66047 _complete@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:60590 complete@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66047 _complete@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66244 complete@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:66047 ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:523900 _trySubscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234913 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234724 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 _innerSub@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:60450 _tryNext@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:60352 _next@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:60190 next@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:65923 ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:523883 _trySubscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234913 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234724 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 subscribe@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:234593 _innerSub@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:414962 _next@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:414799 next@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:65923 notifyNext@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:415333 _next@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:61053 next@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:65923 ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:330519 onInvoke@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:138867 run@ionic://fast.wistia.net/polyfills-es2015.dcbba0ed470a2bbfece2.js:1:1910 ionic://fast.wistia.net/polyfills-es2015.dcbba0ed470a2bbfece2.js:1:12683 onInvokeTask@ionic://fast.wistia.net/main-es2015.a003b1c06f6bc66c5881.js:1:138789 runTask@ionic://fast.wistia.net/polyfills-es2015.dcbba0ed470a2bbfece2.js:1:2529 _@ionic://fast.wistia.net/polyfills-es2015.dcbba0ed470a2bbfece2.js:1:8965 promiseReactionJob@[native code]
```

As far as I can tell, those are the only pieces of code that could be affecting it… but I could be wrong.

Thank you for your time, I appreciate you taking a look! Let me know if there is anymore info you need.

Answer (score 0):

Really easy solution lol. Just needed to add "https:" to my embedded URL link like this:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen *ngIf="sermon?.id === '1'" src="https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/nj4y9f0b7f?playerColor=3EC9A0&autoPlay=true&fullscreenButton=true&playButton=false&playsinline=false&preload=metadata&videoFoam=true&wmode=true&smallPlayButton=true"></iframe>
```

Thanks to everyone that took time to view this! Hope this helps someone in the future!